# Pass Variable to a Popup Window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, window

I need to pass some text from the current page to a popup window without going for a server hit. The information (herewith represented by 90) is already available in the parent form (it's like a paragraph-long text which is stored in a hidden variable). I just need to display that as a popup.

Here's what I've tried, this works to some extent but doesn't work if I pass text, instead of a number. My second concern is that the solution kinda looks ugly. Any tips? Thank you.

This is SCCE, you can run it straight in your machine.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A New Window</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var newWindow;
var data;


function makeNewWindow(param) {
    data = param;

    if (!newWindow || newWindow.closed) {
        newWindow = window.open("","sub","status,height=200,width=300");
        setTimeout("writeToWindow()", 50); /* wait a bit to give time for the window to be created */
    } else if (newWindow.focus) {
        newWindow.focus( ); /* means window is already open*/
    }
}


function writeToWindow() {
    var k = data;
    alert(data);
    var newContent = "<html><head><title>Additional Info</title></head>";
    newContent += "<body><h1>Some Additional Info</h1>";
    newContent += "<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> var localVar; localVar = "+ k +"; document.write('localVar value: '+localVar);</scr"+"ipt>";
    newContent += "</body></html>";
    // write HTML to new window document
    newWindow.document.write(newContent);
    newWindow.document.close( ); // close layout stream
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Create New Window" onclick="makeNewWindow('90');" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, I googled and saw some other approach that uses `window.opener.document.forms.element`, but here, the window has to know in advance what it has to read from the parent. I need to be able to pass it as it will vary:

```
<textarea rows="15" name="projectcontent" id="projectcontent" cols="87"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('viewcon.asp', 'my_new_window','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=625, height=400');"><b>View Content</b></a>

 <head>
 <title>View Project Content</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img src="/images/toplogo.jpg"><br/>
<script language="Javascript">
document.write(window.opener.document.forms['yourformname'].elements['projectcontent'].value)
</script>
 <img src="/images/bottomlogo.jpg">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That's a very dangerous way to use `setTimeout`.  Get rid of the quotation marks and the parentheses!

Comment: How about a modal dialog? `window.open` is so 90s, and lots of users won't see it anyway due to pop-up blockers.

Comment: I'll give points to all answers that make sense.. I promise!

Comment: Thanks! I've attached an edit with some code about window.opener, it's a starting point, try it out and see if it gets you going..good luck!

Answer (score 2):

use window.opener

> From Mozilla Developer Network:
>   When a window is opened from another window, it maintains a reference
>   to that first window as window.opener. If the current window has no
>   opener, this method returns NULL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener

This way you can have on your original window a callback, and you can notify the window it's load and ready, rather than wait a random delay...

you add a function on the original window:

```
   window.popupReady = function (callbackToPopup) {
      callbackToPopup(newData);
   }
```

then the popup can tell the parent window it's ready and pass it a callback to update it with data..

and on the popup try something like:

```
window.dataReady(newData)
{
   alert(newData);
}

document.addEventListener("load", function() { window.opener.popupReady (dataReady); }
```

I didn't test this code, but I would take such a path as this should ensure the popupWindow is ready for you and is along the spirit of JavaScript.

Comment: problem with this, it is how to tell the new window about what to read from parent? please see updated question..

Comment: callback man..it's the way Js is designed..I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: If you could give some prototype that runs, this correct answer is yours. Please?! Have no idea about callbacks yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onclick` attribute you pass '90' to the function, but the function isn't set up to take an argument.  So, change the first line of your function like this:

```
function writeToWindow(data) {
```

You don't need the global `var data;` or the local `var k = data;`, so get rid of them.

And instead of `+ k +` write `+ data +`.

That should do get your data passed.

Comment: sending direct html / or the timeout with string is very bad..do not do it..pass data, it's much safer..

Comment: @DoryZidon, there are lots of things wrong with the OP's code, but I am providing a specific answer to a specific question, not linting the code in general.

Comment: ya I saw your comment too and I agree with it, still, if there is a solution that doesn't involve security risks I be included to suggest it..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it works perfectly in all browsers  .

```
#desc = parent text area id
#desc_textarea = popup 

$("#desc_textarea").val(window.opener.$("#desc").val())
```